# Setting a default value for a variable in a constructor

Tags: c++

I wrote this code and having trouble with passing a three argument constructor that set the first to room number, second to room capacity, **Here is where I'm stuck the three part is to set the room rate, and that sets the room occupancy to 0** here is the code that I wrote

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

class HotelRoom
{
private:
string room_no;
int Capacity;
int occupancy;
double rate;
public:
HotelRoom();
HotelRoom(string, int, int, double );

};  
HotelRoom::HotelRoom (string room, int cap, int occup = 0, double rt )
{
room_no = room;
Capacity = cap;
occupancy = occup;
rate = rt;

cout << " Room number is " << room_no << endl;
cout << " Room Capacity is " << Capacity << endl;
cout << " Room rate is " << rate << endl;
cout << "Occupancy is " << occup << endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{

cout << setprecision(2)
     << setiosflags(ios::fixed)
     << setiosflags(ios::showpoint);

HotelRoom Guest (" 123", 4, 55.13);


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
HotelRoom::HotelRoom (string room, int cap, int occup = 0, double rt )
```

is illegal, if you provide default values they must either

- Have no arguments afterwards
- all arguments following must also have a default value

To work around this make your occup the last variable in your consructor.

```
HotelRoom::HotelRoom (string room, int cap, double rt, int occup=0 )
```

---

Another note:

Only provide the default value in your **header**, rewriting the default value will give you an error during declaration.

header.h

```
HotelRoom(string,int,double,int occup=0);
```

imp.cpp

```
HotelRoom::HotelRoom (string room, int cap, double rt, int occup ) 
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Gmercer015's answer. In C++11 you can use [delegating constructors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Object_construction_improvement).

```
HotelRoom::HotelRoom (string room, int cap, int occup, double rt )
{
    ...
}

HotelRoom::HotelRoom (string room, int cap, double rt )
    : HotelRoom(room, cap, 0, rt)
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR, parameters with default values cannot be followed by parameters without. In your case you should have rate precede occupancy of the latter can have a default value while the former cannot.